# ive made me an xcode 3.2.4 with all sdk´s from 3.0 to 4.1 - works, but i am missing the version-choice in the dropdown

Tags: iphone, xcode

as i got really on edge due apples sdk-politic with the new xcode-versions, i composed my own xcode.
until some days i had installed 3.2.2, 3.2.3 and 3.2.4 at the same time - no diskussion, there was no other way. that this is no elegant way i think anybody can understand.
so i just copied the sdk-folders ( /Developer/Platforms/iPhone[OS/Simulator].platform/Developer/SDKs and ../DeviceSupport) into the 3.2.4-Folder.

so, now it is possible for me to connect a 3.0 to 4.1-device to xcode 3.2.4 and all sdks are available and working.

the only thing, that is not working anymore is, that i can not have a choice, which sdk-version to take in the drop-down-menu, that is normally on the front-left-corner. i think you know, which i mean. so that anytime i need to change the sdk i have to go into the projet-settings to select the sdk-version.

so, do you have any idea, what i could have forgot ?

if i select the simulator, i have all available from 3.0 to 4.1. and in the system-profiler all sdks are listed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your target's Get Info panel, Build settings, and set the Base SDK(under Architectures menu) to higher version you installed ( probably 4.1) and the iOS Deployment Target ( Under Deployment menu) to the lower version ( probably 3.0 ).  Also in the Project Info panel, go to General tab and set the Base SDK to higher version.

Hope this will work for you.